# How to stack LSTM on top of CNN in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I made the following neural network model for sound recognition purpose. The flowchart is like the following:

[cnn-lstm-dense-hybrid(please click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVbPM.png)

The idea is the following:

1. I have 2 different input layers, called A and B.

   (i) Input A has **100 time steps**, each step has a 64-dimensional feature vector

   (ii)A 1D CNN layer(Time distributed) will extract features from each time step. The CNN layer contains **64 filters, each has length 16 taps**. Then, a **maxpooling** layer will extract the single maximum value of each convolutional output, so **a total of 64 features** will be extracted at each time step.

   (iii) The output of the CNN layer will be fed into an **LSTM layer with 64 neurons**. Number of recurrence is the same as time step of input, which is 100 time steps. **The LSTM layer should return a sequence of 64-dimensional output** (the length of sequence == number of time steps == 100, so there should be 100*64=6400 numbers).

   (iv) Meanwhile, **input B also has 100 time steps, each step has a 65-dimensional feature vector**, but they are treated differently from input A.

   (v)Input B **is fed into a dense layer (Time distributed) of 65 neurons**, so it should produce a 65-dimensional output **at each time step**.
2. Now, at each time step, we have output from LSTM layer (64 neurons) and Dense layer (65 neurons), we **concatenate** them in a merge layer. Now we get a **129-dimensional vector** at each time step.
3. We feed this vector into **another dense layer, which produces the output** (single neuron, which represents the probability of "is target sound")

[A hand drawn illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMFP9.jpg)

However, I am stuck at the very beginning trying to make 1(i) work. The code of network building is below:

```
mfcc_input = Input(shape=(100,64), dtype='float', name='mfcc_input')
print(mfcc_input)

CNN_out = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 16, activation='relu'))(mfcc_input)
CNN_out = BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001, center=True, scale=True)(CNN_out)
CNN_out = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(64-16+1), strides=None, padding='valid'))(CNN_out)
CNN_out = Dropout(0.4)(CNN_out)


LSTM_out = LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)(CNN_out)

## Auxilliary branch
delta_input = Input(shape=(100,64), dtype='float', name='delta_input')
zcr_input   = Input(shape=(100,1), dtype='float', name='zcr_input')
aux_input   = concatenate([delta_input, zcr_input])
aux_out     = TimeDistributed(Dense(64+1))(aux_input) 

### Merge branches
merged_layer   = concatenate([LSTM_out, aux_out])

## Output layer
output = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(merged_layer)

model = Model(inputs=[mfcc_input, delta_input, zcr_input], outputs=[output])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',
          loss_weights=[1., 0.2])
...(other code here) ...
```

The error at "CNN_out = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 16, activation='relu'))(mfcc_input)" is: **IndexError: list index out of range**

Anyone could help? Greatly appreciate!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup input shape for 1dCNN+LSTM network (Keras)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870386/how-to-setup-input-shape-for-1dcnnlstm-network-keras)