# How to setup input shape for 1dCNN+LSTM network (Keras)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have the following idea to implement:

```
                       Input -> CNN-> LSTM -> Dense -> Output
```

The Input has 100 time steps, each step has a 64-dimensional feature vector

A **Conv1D** layer will extract features at each time step. The CNN layer contains 64 filters, each has length 16 taps. Then, a maxpooling layer will extract the single maximum value of each convolutional output, so a total of 64 features will be extracted at each time step.

Then, the output of the CNN layer will be **fed into an LSTM layer** with 64 neurons. Number of recurrence is the same as time step of input, which is 100 time steps. The LSTM layer should return a sequence of 64-dimensional output (the length of sequence == number of time steps == 100, so there should be 100*64=6400 numbers).

```
input = Input(shape=(100,64), dtype='float', name='mfcc_input')
CNN_out = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 16, activation='relu'))(mfcc_input)
CNN_out = BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001, center=True, scale=True)(CNN_out)
CNN_out = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(64-16+1), strides=None, padding='valid'))(CNN_out)

LSTM_out = LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)(CNN_out)

... (more code) ...
```

But this doesn't work. The second line reports "***list index out of range***" and I don't understand what's going on.

I'm new to Keras, so I appreciate sincerely if anyone could help me with it.

[This picture explains how CNN should be applied to EACH TIME STEP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ublHo.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your input. Your input is of shape `(100, 64)` in which the first dimension is the timesteps. So ignoring that, your input is of shape `(64)` to a `Conv1D`.

Now, refer to the [Keras Conv1D documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv1d), which states that the input should be a 3D tensor `(batch_size, steps, input_dim)`. Ignoring the `batch_size`, your input should be a 2D tensor `(steps, input_dim)`.

So, you are providing 1D tensor input, where the expected size of the input is a 2D tensor. For example, if you are providing Natural Language input to the `Conv1D` in form of words, then there are 64 words in your sentence and supposing each word is encoded with a vector of length 50, your input should be `(64, 50)`.

Also, make sure that you are feeding the right input to LSTM as given in the code below.

So, the correct code should be

```
embedding_size = 50  # Set this accordingingly
mfcc_input = Input(shape=(100, 64, embedding_size), dtype='float', name='mfcc_input')
CNN_out = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 16, activation='relu'))(mfcc_input)
CNN_out = BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001, center=True, scale=True)(CNN_out)
CNN_out = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(64-16+1), strides=None, padding='valid'))(CNN_out)

# Directly feeding CNN_out to LSTM will also raise Error, since the 3rd dimension is 1, you need to purge it as
CNN_out = Reshape((int(CNN_out.shape[1]), int(CNN_out.shape[3])))(CNN_out)

LSTM_out = LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)(CNN_out)

... (more code) ...
```

Comment: My input is the following: each time step I have a length 64 mfcc vector, so the embedding length is 64, not some other values. The spectrogram has indefinite length, but I will feed 1 time step (=64 numbers) to the network at a time. 100 is the truncated back propagation length of LSTM, so that's what I mean by saying "100 time steps". Now, what I want is that, the CNN should convolve within the same time step, meaning that it should take the 64 numbers as its input, and apply filters on this signal which consists of 64 numbers. So I think your code doesn't quite do the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: I uploaded a hand drawn picture to help explain my idea about how CNN should be applied to each time step, not along time.

Comment: Then, just set the `embedding_size` to 1 and reshape your input of  `(100, 64)` to `(100, 64, 1)`. The point is that the input to the `TimeDistributed Conv1D` should be 3D. Reshaping your input to `(100, 64, 1)` will convolve over the 2nd dimension (64) and assume the first dimension to be the timesteps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is only 1 tiny issue. Conv1D expects 3d input, but it is saying my input dim=4 when I reshape it to (100,64,1). I guess there is an implicit batch_size dimension as dim[0]. How should I solve that? By the way, can I use conv2D with kernel dimension=(1,1d_filter_len) in this case, and then reshape the CNN output to (100,num_lstm_neuron) ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but will need to reshape your input to be a 4D tensor as `(100, 1, 64, 1)`. But I do not see it being any useful over Conv1D. They both will be doing the same thing

Comment: Having input shape (100, 64, 1) and use conv1D gives me error on input dimension `Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`, though

Comment: Your tensor needs to be 2D if you are directly using `Conv1D`, so you'll need to drop one dimension. You tensor needs to be 3D if you are using `TimeDistributed Conv1D` and your input shape is correct in that case.